# Is there a way to get build status as a property?

Tags: build, msbuild, continuous-integration, teamcity

I have a ugly Teamcity build configuration using MSBuild. It executes custom application (test runner), which is using custom messaging to report test results to teamcity.

```
##teamcity[testStarted name='test1']
##teamcity[testFailed name='test1' message='failure message' details='message and stack trace']
```

Which show in teamcity in build overview and tests tab.

Teamcity recognizes failed tests and if any test fails, it marks the build as failed:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qz9UT.png

Later in the MSBuild target I would like to label cvs based on the test results.
Is there a way to get the build status (if it is failed, hanging, warning) as a property? something like %build.status%? The format does not matter - if its a string or number.

PS: I know that best solution to my problem would be to modify the application to return non-zero exit code if test fail.

Comment: any %errorlevel% other than 0 means build failed

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit. Eg "*to report test results to teamcity.*" How do these results appear in TC exactly? "*based on the test results*" in what format do you want these results? "*get the build status*" same question. What is build status and/or in what format do you expect it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TeamCty does not seem to expose this directly, but the status can be acquired using the REST api. Here is an example using curl; but you could also uwe PowserShell's Invoke-RestMethod for instance.

Here's the msbuild script that casues test failure I used for testing:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Target Name="Test">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="##teamcity[testStarted name='test1']" />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="##teamcity[testFailed name='test1' message='failure message' details='message and stack trace']" />
  </Target>

</Project>
```

Then the script that gets the current build's status, dumps it to a file, reads the file into an msbuild item and then uses regex to get the status out of it. You just have it to supply the `tc_user` and `tc_password` properties (or allow guest access) and change the url to match your server.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" DefaultTargets="GetBuildStatus">

  <Target Name="RunCurl">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <MyTempFile>curl_out</MyTempFile>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Exec Command="curl http://localhost/httpAuth/app/rest/builds/id:$(teamcity_build_id) -basic -u $(tc_user):$(tc_password) &gt; $(MyTempFile)"/>
    <ReadLinesFromFile File="$(MyTempFile)">
      <Output TaskParameter="Lines" ItemName="CurlOutput"/>
    </ReadLinesFromFile>
    <Delete Files="$(MyTempFile)"/>
  </Target>

  <Target Name="GetBuildStatus" DependsOnTargets="RunCurl">
    <PropertyGroup>
      <CurlOutputFull>@(CurlOutput)</CurlOutputFull>
      <BuildStatus>$([System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Match($(CurlOutputFull), `status="(\w*)"`).Groups[ 1 ].Value)</BuildStatus>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Message Text="BuildStatus = $(BuildStatus)"/>
  </Target>

</Project>
```

This prints:

```
BuildStatus = FAILURE
```